# Purpose of "shutdown", "ftp" users in linux?

Tags: linux, centos

On printing the contents of `/etc/passwd` file, I found there were users named `shutdown`, `mail`, `daemon`, `sshd`, etc. With some users having login shell set as /sbin/nologin, shutdown user has /sbin/shutdown.

Why are these users needed, what task do they perform ?

I am using CentOS 7.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [What's the difference between /sbin/nologin and /bin/false](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10852/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from accounts for individual users system accounts like these are used by the system for performing various tasks. daemon is a user for daemonizing or running background processes / services during init. mail and sshd are used by the services sendmail and sshd respectively.

/sbin/nologin means that the user in question cannot login via a terminal.
/sbin/shutdown might be responsible for a tunneled sudo (root) access internally for allowing shutdown of system as non-root user (for example on the desktop variant of linux).

It is best not to mess with these accounts to ensure proper functioning of your linux system. Unless you are linux admin and would like to harden your system against vulnerabilities and you know exactly what your are doing.